# Electrical issue on throttle press - BMW 328i

Tags: electrical, bmw

So i have a BMW 328i that is having an electrical issue, It seems whenever the throttle is pressed the lights on the dash light up and power to the A/C, Radio, and cooling fan get disconnected. The interior headliner lights turn on by themselves and the windows do not roll up / down.

Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4JIA973FiQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe my first guess is that the voltage regulator is bad. Another possible issue could be the age of the battery itself or loose ground contact.

What I would recommend is to get a scanner that read fault codes from all the modules and do a full system scan. [Here is a guide on how to do that.](https://www.youcanic.com/wiki/read-clear-bmw-fault-codes-all-modules)

The other option is to take the car to a mechanic and let them troubleshoot it.

Comment: This. I used to be "clever" about these things, but the first step in any such scenario is always to check the battery and have it recharged for free at AutoZone or wherever else this is done.